# Proxy Error when trying to Register or Login and no Network response

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-redux

This is my first trial at web development. I used React-Redux and created a React.js app in the client folder. My backend code language is Node.js and MongoDb for my database.

This is my project.

https://github.com/FaridaElOraby/newest_version.git

It is working on my pc but when I tried to run it on another PC, I could not login or register. When I fill in the fields when logging in or registering and press on submit nothing happens. I should get redirected to the homepage or to login page. There is also no network response. I even tried to console the "res" in the backend to see if the info gets passed to the backend, there was nothing. I don't know why the backend does not see my request. There is a proxy error that pops up from localhost:3000 to localhost:5000 (server). If I don't fill in any fields and try to submit, an error pops up in the console Network Error bad request localhost:3000/api/user/register.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using mongoose for the DB at the backend and the mongo link was expired so it returned a network error. I changed the link at the backend with a working one and it wokred.